# Selenium for loop stops after 2 loops

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I want to go extract authors from a page according to different keywords of topics. I use selenium for that with a for loop of the keywords that I defined in a list. It works fine with the first 2 keywords, but it just stops after 2 searches, instead of making another loop with the 3rd keyword. Here is the code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("myUrl")

keys = ['media', 'image', 'video']

try:
  for key in keys:
    searchbox = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    searchbox.send_keys(key)
    searchbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    searchbox.clear()

    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
      EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "substories.search-results-loaded"))
    )

    articles = main.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
    for article in articles:
      author = article.find_elements_by_class_name('crayons-story__secondary.fw-medium')
      print(key, ':', author[0].text)       
except:
  driver.quit()
```

Because there aren't any errors, I have absolutely no idea, what to do.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can start by changing the end to 
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    driver.quit() 
Because right now all your exceptions are caught and you won't be able to see what happens before you call driver.quit()

Comment: Thanks, it did catch the error: "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Comment: If you write the solution in the answer and mark it as resolved, you might help someone else with a similar issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by changing the end to except Exception as e: print(e) driver.quit() Because right now all your exceptions are caught and you won't be able to see what happens before you call driver.quit() –  Magnus Berg Sletfjerding